# Android TCP monitoring app disconnecting slaves?

Tags: android, networking, tcp

I am new to Android studio and TCP itself, I am developing a TCP app to monitor the connections between a master and several slaves, however, the master will occasionally disconnect all slaves and reconnect after a while, any idea why this is happening or if it has to do with the TCP or just my programming?